# Embed a data.frame into an R script

Tags: r, file, dataframe, default-value

I'm building an R script that requires a file to run. In the huge majority of cases, this file will be the default, but for the times that it's not, I've left the option to change it in docopt.

So my problem is, how do I create a default file? Simply including it in the directory wont work (I may not know the path at runtime, if it's called from somewhere else). My thought then is that I just include the contents of the file in the script itself. I tried this, but it truncates the data and then starts throwing "unexpected symbol" errors (I checked, there are no commas or quotes out of place, and it works fine when loaded from a file anyway). This may be because the file is something like 3800 rows long.

Is there a way to just embed the generated RData into the script itself? Kind of like compiling them together. Or is there something simple I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dput` function to output code that, when read back into a variable, will recreate the object passed originally to `dput`.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, but doesn't that just replace one path I can't track with another?